# Merge array of objects to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of objects like this called `$objects`:

```
object(stdClass)#16 (3) {
  ["subcatname"]=>
  string(22) "Air"
  ["categoryid"]=>
  string(4) "1107"
  ["catname"]=>
  string(18) "Equipment"
}
object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
  ["subcatname"]=>
  string(17) "Machines"
  ["categoryid"]=>
  string(3) "108"
  ["catname"]=>
  string(18) "Equipment"
}
```

I'd like to ass each object(stdClass) to a an associative array value. So my final array would look like this:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#258 (3) {
    ["subcatname"]=>
    string(22) "Air Recirculation Unit"
    ["categoryid"]=>
    string(4) "1107"
    ["catname"]=>
    string(18) "Catering Equipment"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#257 (3) {
    ["subcatname"]=>
    string(17) "Beverage Machines"
    ["categoryid"]=>
    string(3) "108"
    ["catname"]=>
    string(18) "Catering Equipment"
  }
```

Has anyone done something similar to this before? I'm strugglin to get the desired result. Thanks

edit ->

I've tried this method, but this iterates through each row, not each group:

```
$test = array();
        $count =0;

        foreach ($row as $rows) {

            array_push($test, array($count => $rows));
            $count ++;
        }
```

Comment: I have, I've tried using array_push using the method I've included

Answer (score 0):

You must have a collection or others type for ordered your object for iterate a process for do what do want to do.

Example :
if all your objects are in the collecton you can easily do this for ordered in a table your object

```
$orderedTabObject = array();
foreach($collectionObject as $object)
{
    array_push($object, $orderedTabObject);
}
```

This process can change in dealing with your ordered object (collection, array, etc...) but the spirit of process is the same

You need to read how iterate with this differents ordered type for coding your process ordered objects.